# How to read response using HttpsUrlconnection when transfer encoding is chunked

Tags: java, http, servlets, urlconnection, httpsurlconnection

I am writing a servlet which internally uses HttpsUrlConnection to call another Url. From the servlet, I have to return the same response and same response headers that I receive from the HttpsUrlConnection call.

For that, I was reading all the headers using `getHeaderFields()`: copy the headers returned to the Httpservletresponse object of my servlet.

Also, After that I am trying to read response after that using `connection.getErrorStream()` (this is mostly happening when server returns status > 400), thats why I use getErrorStream. Then I read the bytes and copy the bytes to HttpServletResponse outputstream of my servlet.

Now this is working fine is some cases.

But when the server that I call using the connection returns response with Transfer Encoding chunked, then when I call my servlet API, it is returning an error for invalid chunk encoding if I copy the response and response headers to the Httpservlet response.

In this case, in the logs I see that when I read the headers using getHeaderFields, the first header that i see is Transfer encoding chunked, then the next header name is null and it has value HTTP 1/1 .

Also, the response I see is also not proper.

How to read the response headers and the response body in this case from the httpsurlconnection and return that from my servlet properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a similar issue with chunked encoding. The difference to you is that my servlet used HTTP instead of HTTPS internally.

I use a method to copy the header fields, too. But I supply a list of headers that are managed by the servlet container, so I don't create, copy or edit them:

```java
 private static final Set forbiddenCopyHeaders = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{
            "connection"
            , "transfer-encoding"
            , "content-length"
            , "via"
            , "x-forwarded-for"
            , "x-forwarded-host"
            , "x-forwarded-server"
    }));
```

These are the methods I use for copying the response headers:

```
  private void copyResponseHeaders(CloseableHttpResponse internResponse, HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        Header[] headers = internResponse.getAllHeaders();
        Header[] connHeaders = internResponse.getHeaders("connection");
        StringBuilder connectionValue = new StringBuilder();

        for (Header connHeader : connHeaders)
        {
            connectionValue.append(connHeader.getValue()).append(", ");
        }

        for (Header header : headers)
        {
            String headerName = header.getName();

            boolean copyAllowed = !forbiddenCopyHeaders.contains(headerName.toLowerCase())
                    && !StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(connectionValue.toString(), headerName);

            if (copyAllowed)
            {
                if (response.containsHeader(headerName))
                {
                    response.addHeader(headerName, header.getValue());
                }
                else
                {
                    response.setHeader(headerName, header.getValue());
                }
            }
        }

        setViaHeader(internResponse, response);
    }
```

Method setViaHeader():

```
private void setViaHeader(CloseableHttpResponse response, HttpServletResponse customerResponse)
    {
        String serverHostName = "companyServer";
        try
        {
            serverHostName = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            logger.error("für den VIA-Header kann der Hostname nicht ermittelt werden", e);
            System.err.println("für den VIA-Header kann der Hostname nicht ermittelt werden: " +
                    ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
        }

        Header[] originalViaHeaders = response.getHeaders("via");
        StringBuilder via = new StringBuilder("");
        if ((originalViaHeaders != null) && (originalViaHeaders.length > 0))
        {
            for (Header viaHeader : originalViaHeaders)
            {
                via.append(viaHeader.getValue()).append(", ");
            }
        }
        via.append(response.getStatusLine().getProtocolVersion().toString()).append(" ").append(serverHostName);

        customerResponse.setHeader("via", via.toString());
    }
```